# Perl doesn't print 0x00

Tags: exploit, perl

I wanted to experiment with the NOP SLED technique. I got the sled and the shellcode into an environment variable and I got its address.
So i wanted to execute the vulnerable program and as an argument use this address repeated,
the problem is that it contain 0s (zeros): `0x00007fffffffe550`

```
./program_vuln $(perl -e 'print "\x50\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00"')
```

Perl does not print the zeroes and the addressing in the stack became so messed up.

Comment: This appears to be a perl use question and not an InfoSec question.

Comment: perl used in infoSec :)

Comment: But a perl expert with 0 knowledge of InfoSec could also answer this question, no?

Comment: While the application is InfoSec, the underlying problem is not an InfoSec problem - it's a Perl problem.

Comment: Are you sure this belongs on Super User? This sort of question is about programming and it likely belongs on [so] instead.

Comment: problem solved by Steffen Ullrich while you guys are talking about if it is the right place to post this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with perl because it is obviously printing the 0x00:

```
perl -e 'print "\x50\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00"' | hd
00000000  50 e5 ff ff ff 7f 00 00                           |P.......|
00000008
```

Comment: What worked like a charm here? The stack isn't messed up anymore?